# "register" package strange behavior

Tags: bugs, nameref

When I use a `register` package in my document, the `nameref` is not working correctly.
For example, below document shows wrong chapter name.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage[color]{register}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{Wrong section}

\chapter{Chapter 2}\label{chap2}

\chapter{Chapter 3}
\section{Section 3}

Expected: Chapter 2

Got: \nameref{chap2}

\end{document}
```

If I remove a `register` package, the `nameref` is working correctly.

What I can do to fix it?

Comment: load nameref later. The register package redefines \@chapter, and so destroys the nameref additions (it would be better if it would use etoolbox to patch the command).

Comment: Great! It works. Thank you.